# Count the same numbers in rows and columns php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySql table like this :

```
+----+----+----+
| g1 | g2 | g3 |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 5  |
+----+----+----+
| 5  | 1  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+
```

And I need get output in PHP like:

```
number 1 is used 4 times
number 2 is used 1 time
number 3 is used 2 times
```

I make some code but it only write me how many time I used the number and I don't know how to add whitch number.
Thi is my code:

```
for ( $i=1 ; $i<=20; $i++){

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT g1, g2, g3d FROM users 
            WHERE g1 = $i OR g2 = $i OR g3 = $i ") or die(mysql_error()) ;

            $row1 = mysql_num_rows($query);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)    ;
            if ($row1 >=1){echo $row1; }
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: technically this is a variant of a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. the workarounds get very ugly, very fast. if you only EVER need to check for 1/2/3, then it's not totally horrible, but the workarounds can NOT handle 1/2/3/.../n arbitrary transformations. you're probably better off implementing the counting logic in client-side code, and just doing a conventional `select * from ...` query.

Comment: use SELECT count(*) FROM users instead SELECT g1, g2, g3 FROM users.. and i guess an additional d(g3d) is there may causing the issue.

Comment: Per your example, what happens if `g1`, `g2`, or `g3` are ever greater than 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing it this way:

```
// Will be used to keep track of how many times a certain number has appeared
$counter = array();

// Just get all of the rows from the table
$query = mysql_query("SELECT g1, g2, g3 FROM users");

// Loop all rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    // Loop each column: g1, g2, and g3
    foreach($row as $k=>$v)
    {
        // Use the column's value as the array key and let the value be the count of occurrences
        $counter[$v] = (isset($counter[$v]) ? ++$counter[$v] : 1);
    }
}

// Sort based on key from low to hi
ksort($counter);

// Loop the tracker and echo whatever you need
foreach($counter as $k=>$v)
{
    echo 'number '.$k.' is used '.$v.' time'.($v === 1 ? '' : 's').'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have that number in your `$i` variable

```
if ($row1 >= 1) { echo 'number ' . $i . 'is used' . $row1 . 'times'; }
```